# How to create a brew formula with jar file?

Tags: java, jar, homebrew

I have two files: a jar file and run.sh script to run the jar. I want to run it through the Home Brew.

What should I do to make it possible? Should I create a `tar.gz` file?

Comment: Do you mean you want to *distribute* it through homebrew, as opposed to just running the Java program?

Comment: Yes, I want to distribute it through homebrew. Is it possible?

Comment: I did find this: https://blog.srcclr.com/distribute-your-java-app-via-brew/

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is a very useful link.